# Custom UIBarButtonItem not working with appearance

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

i have subClass from UIBarButtonItem, when set setBackgroundImage with appearance not working, but create subClass from UIButton set image worked!.

my code:

```
MyCustomBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "back_image"), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must create subClass from `UIButton` and assign to `customView` property in subClass from UIBarButtonItem and set image background to custom UIButton.
for more information you can see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66074112/5140621